# Unexpected open() filesystem from Nginx

Tags: nginx

**Hello!**

I've come up with a strange Nginx behavior within my nginx configuration.

After following [this blog post](http://linuxplayer.org/2013/06/nginx-try-files-on-multiple-named-location-or-server) to be able to handle multiple **named-locations**, I quickly realised that I was filling my nginx error logs.
Indeed, for every request that didn't match a static file I kept on having a filesystem open error: `[error] 11111#0: *20 open() "/www/hello/action" failed (2: No such file or directory)`

**with this nginx configuration:**

```
server {

  root /www/hello;

  location / {
    try_files /non-existent-4-ever @all;
  }

  location @all {
    # Expecting Nginx to serve static files and return 404 for non existent files
    error_page 404 = @backend;
  }

  location @backend {
    return 200 "hello";
  }

}
```

**And these files:**

```sh
root@somewhere:/www/hello$ ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6 Sep 23 13:45 file1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6 Sep 23 13:45 file2.txt
```

via:

```sh
root@somewhere:/www/hello$ curl localhost/file1.txt
content_file1.txt
```

I can successfully get the content of the static files

via:

```sh
root@somewhere:/www/hello$ curl localhost/action
hello
```

I successfully get the result from my `@backend` (which always returns `hello`)

But I also get an error in the nginx error log:

```
root@somewhere:/www/hello$ tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log 
2014/09/23 13:50:13 [error] 111111#0: *19 open() "/www/hello/action" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.42.1, server: , request: "GET /action HTTP/1.1", host: "172.17.0.2:80"
```

**Do you guys think this is a bug in Nginx?**

*PS:* I solved the error logging by adding a check on the file in the second **named-location** as following:

```
  location @all {
    # Expecting Nginx to serve static files and return 404 for non existent files
    error_page 404 = @backend;

    if ( !-f $request_filename ) {
      return 404;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the error log is explained in both the blog and the documentation: try_files also sets log_not_found to off.

Since you don't show the status returned in a failing `@all`, I assume it's a 5xx error and if that's the case, your fix should be to turn on recursive error pages, also mentioned in the blog.

Comment: Cheers @Melvyn, this part of the doc didn't reach my eyes I guess. You made my good answer!